# When to clear a canvas when redrawing images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, profiling

I am working on a web app that does some face detection from webcam. I am using WebRTC and I use the `ctx.drawImage()` method to draw the `video` element into the canvas.

On top of this image I draw a rectangle to outline the face. I repeat this 15 times if the webcam fps is 15. But I don't clear the canvas anywhere. I don't see any lag after a couple of minutes of streaming the webcam content into the canvas and doing the face detection.

I tried using the memory profiler in chrome devtools to see if there are some alarming spikes. I am a little worried because there is **NOT** anything fishy going on there. But there should be a spike right? I mean, I redraw an image on the canvas, every couple of milliseconds. Does that not mean, I'd have layers of each frame and a rectangle stacked on top of another. There will be 15 such layers in a second! This sounds pretty alarming to me.

I want to understand, how should I debug the canvas profiling feature. I realised it got removed after [Chrome 44](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802514/how-to-inspect-canvas-frames). Also, anyone gone through the same situation, what's the best way of showing every frame then. Should I not have to clear the canvas after every frame? If I should clear it, what's the best way of doing that. I hope I could explain my problem here.

## Edit

1. For someone wanting to see this in action. I have put together a simple  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au7ow18r/) to demonstrate `clearRect` as suggested by @touko. Uncomment the last line, and it clears it totally. NO layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you draw something on the canvas it overrides the current information in that location -> one canvas will never have multiple 'layers' on it.

Eg. you have to call clearRect, which essentially writes new data to the canvas, to 'clear' the canvas

Comment: So, if the canvas never has multiple layers, why use `clearRect`? I am sorry but I couldn't get your point entirely I suppose.

Comment: I got your point. Put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au7ow18r/) to understand it completely. Thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: ClearRect is used to clear canvas. Suppose you have drawn two circle and now you want to draw a rectangle but remove circles. In that case you will need to clear the canvas which will erase circles and then draw rectangle.  Checkout this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743699/is-clearing-canvas-2d-context-in-html5-necessary-for-good-performance